# How to cycle through all widget in a QVBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt4.8

I have a QVBoxLayout created through the drag and drop section.
Inside of it AT RUN TIME I insert some widgets with the command

ui->verticalLayout->insertWidget()  //using appropriate options.

All widgets I insert are of the same type/class.

I would like to cycle through the inserted widgets in order to perform some actions over them.

I suppose it is really simple but can't seem to find out how...

thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QLayout::itemAt()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#itemAt) to loop on the items of the layout. Then use [QLayoutItem::widget()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayoutitem.html#widget) to get the widget:

```
for(int i = 0; i < layout->count(); ++i)
{
    do_something(
        layout->itemAt(i)->widget()
    );
}
```

Note that `widget()` may return a null pointer.

Comment: I know I may be asking much, but could you show me some sample code please?

Comment: It should be something like that:

    for (int i = 0; i < layout->count(); ++i)
        do_something( layout->itemAt(i)->widget() );

Take care the widget() method may return a null pointer.

Comment: Thank you very much!

You have really been helpful!